# Is it also correct if I answer $60\times 250$ as the estimation for $57\times 246$?

Tags: soft-question, education, estimation

In a textbook I use for teaching, I found the following.

[image]

## Question

Why are there only two possibilities?
Is it also correct if I answer $60\times 250$ as the estimation for $57\times 246$?

Comment: I am afraid I will be propagating a wrong answer to my students.

Comment: It seems very reasonable to estimate the way you did...That's how I would have done it. What exactly is this covering?

Comment: Maybe the idea is that if you are overestimating one term, you should underestimate the other, and vice versa? $60 \times 250$ overestimates both terms. Although $60 \times 250$ is factually a closer estimation than the two given...

Comment: Estimate is really poorly defined here. I can make the terrible estimate of $1$ and it is still an estimate.

Comment: It is just a material for junior high school students preparing IGCSE exams.

Comment: Maybe the real question he is asking is which number is closer to the actual value.

Comment: The book does not say "Here are **the only** two possibilities."  It say "Here are two possibilities."  It does not preclude the existence of others.  Your estimate looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working noting that your estimate (15000) is better than theirs since the actual product is 14022 even though you would go into it knowing that it was an overestimate.

As a high school math teacher, I've never heard of a strategy for teaching estimation as being wrong.  At worst, your students will miss one question on a bogus standardized test.  If you can train them to quickly estimate what an answer will be before they calculate it so that they can actually strive to understand the results of their work, that is a really really small price to pay.

Answer (score 1):

The authors did *not* claim there were **only** two possibilities. They simply listed two as examples and (presumably) left the rest for anyone to come up with. Indeed, they couldn't have listed all possibilities if they'd wanted to as there are infinitely many.